# SQL - Getting only the row with maximum value in one column for matching values in another column

Tags: sql-server

I have several columns.

```
ID - unique id for each row
Key - Correlating to a specific action (there is occasional duplicates)
Date - Lists the date and time for when each ID was created
```

I need to find a way to only the row with the greater ID when I have duplicate Keys.

What I have:

```
Select t1.*
From log as t1
Where t1.ID = (Select Max(t2.ID) From log as t2 Where t2.Key = t1.Key)
Order By ID
```

This gets rid of a LOT of rows though, including some non-duplicates (but not ALL non-duplicates)

For examples of some things that disappear:

```
key 107914 -> logs [4360, 4361] Stays with 4361
key 107928 -> logs [4347, 4349, 4351, 4354, 4357] Gone
key 119207 -> logs [1189, 724] Gone
key 105079 -> logs [3399] Gone
key 107309 -> logs [4364] Stays with 4364
key 119210 -> logs [898] Gone
```

Comment: When you say 'gets rid of'...Do you mean SELECTs the rows that are duplicates?  (And you want to fix the SELECT so that it only has duplicates?)

Comment: Is it mysql or sql server? those are very different database engines, and for this particular question Sql Server has some features that will make this much easier.

Comment: This is sql server sorry. I want no duplicates of the Keys and only the row with the largest ID value for each Key. Basically I want to make the Key column unique with only the latest keys of the same value.

Comment: Your query is correct. Provide some examples of non dupes that are being removed because it shouldn't be

Comment: Added some examples of both duplicates and non duplicates and when they stay and when they don't

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work, but only for Sql Server. If you're using MySql, the answer is more complicated.

```
select r.* 
from (
    select distinct key from log
) k
cross apply (select top 1 * from log l where l.key = k.key order by id desc) r
```

Comment: This gave me the same result as my query from above. Though I am still not sure as to why it doesn't keep some of the keys visible.

Comment: This seems to be working now actually. Apparently I think there was an issue with some LIKE filters I had that was causing the issue. So then my original query also worked. I'll mark you as best answer though.